# Algorithm for a health/activity score for completing tasks on a website

Tags: algorithm

We're creating a basic site where users get to-do's delivered to them each week.  I need to create an algorithm which based on there completion (or lack there of) of these to-do's, I assign them a health score of 0 - 100.

There are 0 - 4 to-do's delivered each week.
A to-do can be completed, deleted (marked as irrelevant), or left pending.

If users aren't completing their to-do's (to-do's in the pending state) then they have a low health meter.

I'd also like to weight the pending states.  For example pending to-do's in the first week aren't as detrimental to the score as pending to-do's in the 4th week.  I'm only thinking of using the last 4-6 weeks of data to determine the score.

Any help with the approach I should take would be much appreciated.

I'm currently using the following notation

```
t0     # total to-dos given in week 0
t0_c   # completed to-dos from week 0
t0_d   # deleted to-dos from week 0
t0_p   # pending to-dos from week 0
```

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the perfect place for a [Moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).

Example:
health for a week = 100*((not done for that week)^1.5)/8
Then use an [exponential moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) on the historical and current health scores to get the current health.

Answer (score 1):

May be you could assign completion scores each week and assign weight-age for each week's completion scores. Since you are considering say only last 5 weeks of scores, you could have something like (1 for completion, 0 for pending)

```
 week 1 [1,0,0,1]   completion score = 50%
 week 2 [1,0,1]     completion score = 66.6%
 week 3 [0]         completion score = 0%
 week 4 [1]         completion score = 100%
 week 5 [1,0,0,0]   completion score = 25%
```

All dont have total of 4 to-dos as some may be irrelevant

Now you assign weekly weights, you know week1 is 5 weeks back and so should have more weight and eventually comes down at week 5, so something like

```
week1 weight = 30%
week2 weight = 25%
week3 weight = 20%
week4 weight = 15%
week5 weight = 10%
```

Now just multiply week's completion score to its weight and add the terms

```
(50*30 + 66.6*25 + 25*0 + 15*100 + 25*10)/100 = 49.15%
```

One downside to this approach is that,

Say Guy1 week1 has 1 to-do pending i.e

```
week 1 [0]  => score = 0%
```

Say Guy2 week1 has 2 to-do pending but one complete i.e

```
week 1 [0,0,1]  => score = 33%
```

Guy2 gets much higher score though he has more pending work

If number of to-dos are roughly same among the customers on an average then this wont be a big issue.